# How do I use jQuery to remove the last ` · ` from the my code

Tags: jquery, html

How do I use jQuery to remove the last `·` from the follow code:

```
<div class="twtr-tweet-text">
 <em> 
  <a href="" class="twtr-timestamp" target="_blank">about 1 hour ago</a>
   · 
  <a href="" class="twtr-reply" target="_blank">reply</a>
   · 
  <a href="" class="twtr-rt" target="_blank">retweet</a>
   · 
  <a href="" class="twtr-fav" target="_blank">favorite</a>
 </em>
</div>
```

The HTML is pulled from Twitter, so I have no control over its creation.

Comment: what do you mean by last .??? are you talking about the . between retweet and favorite?

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh Yes that is the `.` I need to remove

Comment: [Consider using a UL element for your list of links](http://memegenerator.net/instance/13964090)

Answer (score 2):

Your `.` has no wrapper, so you will need to use `.contents` in order to get text nodes.  You can then loop over all of the text nodes.

```
$("#twtr-tweet-text").contents().each(function(){
    if(this.nodeType == 3){
        // text node
        // do your thing here, check if it's a . etc.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @James Any way to target the last instance rather than the 3rd?

Comment: The 3 is not to get the third, `nodeType == 3` indicates that it is a text node.  I would probably loop backwards through `contents` and then the first one you find is actually the last.

Comment: I still can't work out how to hide or remove the `.` So to be daft :( can't you give me any direction here?

Comment: Post what you have tried and I will help you with it.  I prefer not to write the entire code for you.

Comment: I've been shooting in the dark and reading jquery functions for about an hour. I got nothin!!

Comment: this may also be relevent.. I'm using jQuery 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a lateral solution, but instead of adding the `·` separator on the server-side, you can add it with CSS like:

```
.twtr-tweet-tex a:before {
  content:'·';
}

.twtr-tweet-tex em a:first-child:before {
  content: none;
}
```

Then you don't need to remove it with jQuery.